# Update data with Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress, entity-framework-6

I am developing a WPF desktop app with .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 6.1.3 with code first from database approach.

The database is PostgreSQL and the data provider is EntityFramework6.Npgsql.

The Items source for the Grid is dx:EntitySimpleDataSource

The problem is when I try to save entities from DevExpress WPF Datagrid control updating entity by changing state to EntityState.Modified throw this exception :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

But saving new ones just works fine.

Here is my code

```
private void SaveData()
{
    using (var context = new DataEntityModel())
    {
        try
        {
            List<int> handles = GetDataRowHandles();

            foreach (int rowHandle in handles)
            {
                category category = (category)CategoriesDataTable.GetRow(rowHandle);

                if (category == null)
                    continue;

                context.Entry(category).State = category.id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
}

private List<int> GetDataRowHandles()
{
    List<int> rowHandles = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < CategoriesDataTable.VisibleRowCount; i++)
    {
        int rowHandle = CategoriesDataTable.GetRowHandleByVisibleIndex(i);
        if (CategoriesDataTable.IsGroupRowHandle(rowHandle))
        {
            if (!CategoriesDataTable.IsGroupRowExpanded(rowHandle))
            {
                rowHandles.AddRange(GetDataRowHandlesInGroup(rowHandle));
            }
        }
        else
            rowHandles.Add(rowHandle);
    }
    return rowHandles;
}

private List<int> GetDataRowHandlesInGroup(int groupRowHandle)
{
    List<int> rowHandles = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < CategoriesDataTable.GetChildRowCount(groupRowHandle); i++)
    {
        int rowHandle = CategoriesDataTable.GetChildRowHandle(groupRowHandle, i);
        if (CategoriesDataTable.IsGroupRowHandle(rowHandle))
        {
            rowHandles.AddRange(GetDataRowHandlesInGroup(rowHandle));
        }
        else
            rowHandles.Add(rowHandle);
    }
    return rowHandles;
}
```

Category.cs

```
[Table("public.categories")]
public partial class category
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public category()
    {
        items = new HashSet<item>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your DevExpress datasource is using a different context and is still referencing the object you are trying to update.

Comment: The datasource is defined in the XAML file.How to get that different context or how to resolve this exception?

Comment: You could try getting the context instance that fetched your record and use it for saving too unless you want to detach it from the context that loaded the record. You are defining var context = new DataEntityModel().

Comment: And how to get that context?